# Como hago para que las cards queden en el lugar donde quiero que esten? se me colocan aleatoreamente al moverlas

Tags: angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
onDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log(event)

    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      )
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      )
    }
  }
```

```css
este es mi archivo JSON

https://run.mocky.io/v3/3d4ef214-70a5-494e-ae7e-aaea04c4d393
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tarjetas">
    <div cdkDropListGroup *ngFor="let dash of dashboard">
      <div class="card-columns">
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="dash.tituloFleet"
          #todolist="cdkDropList"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDropped($event)"
        >
          <div class="card" *ngFor="let fleet of dash.tituloFleet" cdkDrag>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ fleet.name }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="dash.tituloCarriers"
          #todolist="cdkDropList"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDropped($event)"
        >
          <div class="card" *ngFor="let carrier of dash.tituloCarriers" cdkDrag>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ carrier.name }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="dash.tituloBASIC"
          #todolist="cdkDropList"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDropped($event)"
        >
          <div class="card" *ngFor="let basic of dash.tituloBASIC" cdkDrag>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ basic.name }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-columns">
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="dash.tituloStatus"
          #todolist="cdkDropList"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDropped($event)"
        >
          <div class="card" *ngFor="let status of dash.tituloStatus" cdkDrag>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ status.name }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="dash.tituloExpired"
          #todolist="cdkDropList"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDropped($event)"
        >
          <div class="card" *ngFor="let expired of dash.tituloExpired" cdkDrag>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ expired.name }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="dash.tituloRated"
          #todolist="cdkDropList"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDropped($event)"
        >
          <div class="card" *ngFor="let rated of dash.tituloRated" cdkDrag>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ rated.name }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-columns">
        <div
          cdkDropList
          [cdkDropListData]="dash.tituloReport"
          #todolist="cdkDropList"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDropped($event)"
        >
          <div class="card" *ngFor="let report of    dash.tituloReport" cdkDrag>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">{{ report.name }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

esta es mi pagina lo que quiero es que cuando arrastro por ejemplo la card SAFETY RATING a RATED CARRIERS quede en el lugar donde estaba RATED CARRIERS o tambien cuando paso por ejemplo cuando arrastre a CARRIERS STATUS en la columna de TREND REPORT esta se añade a esa columna.

........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Y si, porque en tu pregunta pusiste solo codigo, sin ninguna clase de ejemplo, imagen (en este caso era valido), explicacion del problema, lo que querias como solucion.. nada.. solo una pared de codigo.. Como podemos saber donde es que querias ponerlas? como podemos saber como deberia ser tu pagina? cuando mejores la pregunta, quitare mi negativo...

Comment: listo ya puse la imagen y la descripcion de lo que quiero